# How to add image upload tag in Struts2 jquery grid plugin

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, jqgrid, grid

I am using struts2 jquery Grid plugin for the admin panel functionality for website.
In this plugin when i click add button it populate form using jquery dialog ui
So here i want to show my form that accepts file uploading & also i have written validation xml file for this form so i want this dialog should show validation errrors if user forgets to enter some information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [edittype:'file'](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#file). For the validation you can use [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) with `custom: true` and define your custom validation in [custom_func](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example).